# Removing text and autosumming in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to sum up the numbers in a certain row by adding a formula in vba but It doesn't seem to like this Formula.

Each Cell Looks like this [ Vertical Lines are not included in cells ]:

```
30 (Gold)  |  25 (Silver)  |  20 (Gold)  |  13 (Green)
```

So it needs to remove everything after "("

```
Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(lastSeasonRow, 14).Formula = "=SUM(LEFT(B" & lastSeasonRow & ":L" & lastSeasonRow & ",InStr(1, B" & lastSeasonRow & ":L" & lastSeasonRow & ","" (""))"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try an array formula involving the [SUMPRODUCT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMPRODUCT-function-57a7bfa7-f74d-4ead-8c93-57f759c8f616) using the [IFERROR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/IFERROR-function-F59BACDC-78BD-4924-91DF-A869D0B08CD5) to discard non-valid/blank entries,

```
With Worksheets("Season 2014-2015").Cells(lastSeasonRow, 14)
    .FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(VALUE(LEFT(TRIM(B" & lastSeasonRow & ":L" & lastSeasonRow & "), FIND(CHAR(32), TRIM(B" & lastSeasonRow & ":L" & lastSeasonRow & "&CHAR(32))))), 0))"
End With
```

I used `CHAR(32)` ([CHAR function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CHAR-function-F3B7D2E6-0ED5-40E6-92A3-E5ACAF9B4225)) because I avoid dealing with quotes in quoted strings. The [TRIM function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/TRIM-function-50B6F593-4801-4F06-81C5-3345E7F80DDD) can be left out if you do not have any leading spaces in the actual data.

[image: SUMPRODUCT with IFERROR to total text numbers]

Comment: Thank you Jeeped, it does work. The problem I was having now was that since some cells in the row are blank they get placed with a #VALUE!, when I change them to Zeroes, it shows up correctly. Trying to add if cell blank then add 0 to the formula

Comment: I wrapped an extra layer of processing into the mix. See above for modification to the array formula solution. I removed the standard formula solution.